# Django: when creating custom user, ValueError: Dependency on unknown app

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users, django-custom-user

I'm building a brand-new web project with Python 3.4.3 and Django 1.8 without any migrations made so far. For the project, I'm creating a custom user inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` in an app called `users`. I've also correctly referred `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to the custom user in `settings.py`, before creating any migrations, as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

However, when I tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations users` or `python manage.py migrate`, the console reports `ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: users`.

I'm pretty sure my code for the custom user model is correct because I followed documentation's example code, and also because, when I commented out `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, everything else worked fine except that Django created tables for the default User model, which is expected.

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) it is mentioned that:

> you must ensure that the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL is created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you will have dependency issues.

I'm not very sure what exactly this means. Does it mean that I have to manually create a migration for my `users` app? If so, how exactly should I do it?

I greatly appreciate any suggestion or redirection to a credible source! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: did u run ./manage.py migrate first?

Comment: Hi @levi! Thank you very much for your quick response! the doc says that "If you intend to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you should set it before creating any migrations or running `manage.py migrate` for the first time." Therefore I did not run `./manage.py migrate` first. Is that something that I should have done? However, running `./manage.py migrate` would have created table for the default user model, which is not what I want. I guess my question is: how can I create a model in the first migration without also creating table for the default user? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after trying various approaches to tackle the problem, I found that the problem lie in an accidental mistake. In the `users` directory, I've deleted all the files in `migrations` directory including its `__init__.py`. If there is no `__init__.py` file, the `ValueError` will be thrown. If you manually add the `__init__.py` file, everything works like a charm.

To those having the same problem, good luck!

Comment: It works but you may need to delete all migration files those depend to the app you are working on. After deleting migrations run makemigrations and migrate commands. PS: I am using docker container to run my code and can delete my demo app so please be careful while deleting migrations' files for your projects in product.

Answer (score 0):

For Django 3.2 deleting the migrations directory in the `users` directory and running

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations users
python manage.py migrate
```

worked for me.